# Counting rows matching each of the multiple conditions in MySQL

Tags: mysql, grouping

Please help me figure a single query that will transform the data below...

```
|id |status_a |status_b |
|+++++++++++++++++++++++|
|  1|active   |inactive |
```

...into this one.

```
|status_group      |count|
|++++++++++++++++++++++++|
|status_a.active   |    1|
|status_b.inactive |    1|
```

edit: If a single pass query is possible then that will be better. Also, does a query with unions does a single pass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If status can be either only `active` or `inactive`, I'd suggest a different approach:

```
SELECT
    sum(if(status_a='active',1,0)) AS status_a_active,
    sum(if(status_a='inactive',1,0)) AS status_a_inactive,
    sum(if(status_b='active',1,0)) AS status_b_active,
    sum(if(status_b='inactive',1,0)) AS status_b_inactive
FROM table
```

Otherwise you need to use the `UNION` approach, but I'd do it a little differently. First, you can use `UNION ALL`, because you don't need to remove duplicates in the result. I'd also use `GROUP BY` only once like this:

```
SELECT status_group, count(id)
FROM (
    SELECT CONCAT('status_a.', status_a) AS status_group, id FROM table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CONCAT('status_b.', status_b) AS status_group, id FROM table
) a
GROUP BY status_group
```

Comment: Well, I instead move the status into a different table. I made use of column aggregation for easy relationship lookup

Comment: instead of using `IF`s you can just select boolean values which will become 1 or 0: `SELECT SUM(status_a='active') AS status_a_active, ...`

Answer (score 2):

I have a solution that uses UNIONs. Shown here:

```
SELECT 'status_a.active' AS status_group, COUNT(*) AS count FROM `test` WHERE status_a = 'active'
UNION
SELECT 'status_a.inactive' AS status_group, COUNT(*) AS count FROM `test` WHERE status_a = 'inactive'
UNION
SELECT 'status_b.active' AS status_group, COUNT(*) AS count FROM `test` WHERE status_b = 'active'
UNION
SELECT 'status_b.inactive' AS status_group, COUNT(*) AS count FROM `test` WHERE status_b = 'inactive'
```

Basically, it queries each condition for status_a or status_b being active or not. We get four such queries and we apply UNION to all of them.

Comment: that was also my coworker's solution but i was not contented, i even rewrote them into like this...

    SELECT CONCAT('status_a.', status_a) AS stat, COUNT(id) FROM base GROUP BY stat
    UNION
    SELECT CONCAT('status_b.', status_b) AS stat, COUNT(id) FROM base GROUP BY stat

still, I'm looking for something that doesn't require unions if it's worth the speedup.

Comment: This is both inefficient and incorrect. You don't need 4 scans over the table, and you are missing `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Hi luke, that's why I'm here to ask. I really like your suggestion. I havn't thought of using derived table as source

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, I've to move my comment a while ago which is also a shorter solution here than hw's.

```
SELECT CONCAT('status_a.', status_a) AS stat, COUNT(id) FROM base GROUP BY stat 
UNION
SELECT CONCAT('status_b.', status_b) AS stat, COUNT(id) FROM base GROUP BY stat
```